# How to set correctly phonegap plugins callback

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

Hi I develope a phone gap plugin to see if a directory is empty.

I use the below code

```
        public PluginResult execute(String arg0, final JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {

        if ( arg0.equals(SHOW6) )
        {

            PluginResult result = null;

                    File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista/todesktop/");

                    if(file.isDirectory()){

                        if(file.list().length>0){

                        /*  Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                            dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                            AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                            alert.setTitle("Failure");
                            alert.setMessage("Directory is not empty!");
                            alert.show();
                        */
                            return new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, "Directory is not empty!");
                        //  System.out.println("Directory is not empty!");

                        }else{

                        /*                      
                            Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                            dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                            AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                            alert.setTitle("Failure");
                            alert.setMessage("Directory is empty!");
                            alert.show();
                        */       
                            return new PluginResult(Status.OK, "Directory is empty!");
                    //      System.out.println("Directory is empty!");

                        }

                    }else{

                //      System.out.println("This is not a directory");

                    }

        }
```

And this is how I call it from js

```
var msgbox = function() {
};

msgbox.prototype.show6 = function(success, fail) {
    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "msgbox", "show6", []);
    };  

function success(e){globalcreate = 0; alert(e);}
function fail(r){globalcreate = 1; alert(r);}

msgbox = new msgbox();
```

I want to alert if directory is or not empty.

How to set the callbacks?

If I uncomment the alert dialog at my .java Ι receive the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a scoping problem. Declaring the success and failure methods as globals is a bad idea. You want to do something like this:

```
var msgbox = function() { 
};

msgbox.prototype.show6 = function(success, fail) {
    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "msgbox", "show6", []);
};  

function showSuccess(e){globalcreate = 0; alert(e);}
function showFail(r){globalcreate = 1; alert(r);}

msgbox = new msgbox();
```

and call it like:

```
msgbox.show6(showSuccess, showFail);
```

Alternatively you always want to do the same thing you can pull them in your method like:

```
msgbox.prototype.show6 = function() {
    var win = function(e){globalcreate = 0; alert(e);}
    var fail = function(r){globalcreate = 1; alert(r);}
    return PhoneGap.exec(win, fail, "msgbox", "show6", []);
};
```

and call it like:

```
msgbox.show6();
```

The Java code you have commented out should always [run on the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) if you don't do that it will cause you problems.